# Eclipse project not built on Mac OS X: 'A resource exists with a different case' error

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, hfs+

I have some code, I inherited that was previously build on a Linux system. I tried to build it on Mac OS X Snow Leopard. My partition is Mac OS Extended (journaled). I know this is a case insensitive file system and the errors comes from 2 java classes that have the same name but different case. So that error is "normal".

I tried to find a way around it, so I have build a Disk Image with the file system partition Mac OS X Extended (Journaled, Case-sensitive). On that volume I can create two files with the same name and different in case.

I copied my project on it, but the error remained. I then created a new workspace on that volume and imported the project in that workspace, but the error still remains. I would think that the setting for that would be stored on Workspace level.

Where does Eclipse store the "case-sensitive" / "case-insensitive" flag or why does Eclipse still generates this error although the workspace and project are on a case-sensitive volume. Is there a way this could work on Mac OS X on a case-sensitive partition?

I know I could just rename the classes, but the code is a bit funky and it is not a simple refactoring in this case.

Thanks

Comment: MUST it build on OS X or is it just the machine you have?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you rename one of the files such that it can exist on a case-insensitive file system.  While you might not have any plans today, you might need to build your product on Windows at some point.

Comment: That isn't the question. Besides it it can require us to modify the hundreds of files to reconcile the new name of a couple of files.